# common function that accept all argument in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

often time I have this pattern problem in javascript. I have an `add` function

`function add(a, b){
 return a + b;
}`

then I can do `add(1,2) //3`

but what if I want to pass in any length of arguments?

I can't do freely `add(1,2,3,4)`. or `add(something,something,something)`. If I want I have to write another add function that accept 4 and 3 arguments.

I know I can use loop them up by loop but how to pass any number of argument to a function in js?

Comment: So loop over the arguments https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1):

you can use arguments property .

```js
function add(){
  var sum=0;
  for (var key in arguments)
    sum=sum+arguments[key];
 return sum;
}
console.log(add(1,2,3,7));
```

Comment: why a for in loop?

Comment: we use for in loop to get the key of object.

Comment: But it is not an object, it is an array like structure.

Comment: @epascarello we can use arguments.length too

Comment: I guess `arguments` is an array like object but is not an array so you will either have to convert it to array or use for..in

Comment: @epascarello whatever it has object or array .but we can use for in loop for both object or array .

Comment: arguments is a reserved words in javascript?

Comment: a native for loop will  be much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @JessieEmerson And `for..in` is not native?

Comment: it is but it's newer than the traditional for loop :P

Comment: @JessieEmerson its supported by [IE6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Browser_compatibility). You cannot go to support before that. Also, `for..in` is the ideal way to loop over objects. **Remember, `arguments` is not an Array**

Comment: why not use native for loop? it's faster than for in.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over arguments and add values

#### ES6

```js
function add(){
  return Array.from(arguments).reduce((p,c)=>p+= !isNaN(c)? +c : 0, 0)
}

console.log(add(1,2,3,4,5))
console.log(add(1,2,3,'a', 7))
```

#### ES5

```js
function add(){
  return [].slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(p,c){
    p+= !isNaN(c)? +c : 0;
    return p;
  }, 0)
}

console.log(add(1,2,3,4,5))
console.log(add(1,2,3,'a', 7))
```

Comment: (With the caveat that you'll need babel or a polyfill for IE and earlier browsers.)

Comment: Oh @DaveNewton would using `[].slice.call(arguments).reduce(...)` make you happy? ;)

Comment: @rajesh why go into ocean when OP asked only one glass of water .

Comment: @DaveNewton I have added handling for both.

Comment: @epascarello Delirious!

Comment: @Mahi My bad. Are you pointing about `!isNaN`?

Comment: this is overkilled

Comment: @JessieEmerson My bad! CS player, bad habit.